# Codeigniter shopping cart insert failed

Tags: codeigniter, cart

I know that this question has already been asked but i still cannot find a solution for this issue;
So, i created an array and tried to insert it into the cart and display the contents but the result is an empty array:
**Controller:**

```
 public function add(){


    $product = $this->emag_model->get_id($this->input->post('product_id'));

    $insert = array(

        'id' =>$product->id,
        'qty'     => 1,
        'price' =>$product->pret,
        'name'    =>  $product->nume,

    );
    $this->cart->insert($insert);

    redirect('emag/chart');
}
public function chart(){
    $this->renders();
      $this->load->view('emag/chart');
}
```

**view:**

```
 <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $laptop->id; ?> " />  
//$laptop->id retrieves the id of the curent product

 <table id="table_cart">


        <tbody>
        <?php foreach( $this->cart->contents() as $item): ?>
        <tr>
            <td>                   
                <?php echo  $item['name']; ?>
            </td>
            <td><?php echo $item['qty']; ?></td>
            <td> <?php echo $item['price']; ?></td>

        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**model:**

```
public function get_id($id){
    $query = $this->db->get_where('laptop_notebook', array('id'=>$id))->result();
    $data = $query[0];
    return $data;
```

I have autoloaded the cart and session libraries, i set `$config['sess_use_database']   = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';` i created that ci_sessions table, but still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Check your $insert it has correct value or not

Comment: which file is this controller or model??

Comment: Some codeigniter cart guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614190/codeigniter-cart-cant-insert-data

Comment: @saty, the controller

Comment: please submit your whole code!!

Comment: @saty, sry, i updated the post

Answer (score 0):

Some attention for successful cart insert:

- price' > 0
- 'name' (or similar field) better not in unicode

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, i don't know why, `$this->input->post('product_id')` was the problem even tho when i echo it, i get the correct id of the product